# Не понятное поведение скрола элемента на Safari (ios)

Tags: javascript, css, safari

Делаю чат. После того как приходит новое сообщение, прокручиваю скролл до конца страницы, что бы отобразить его:

```
 function scrollDown() {
        let scrollbar = document.querySelector('.content');
         scrollbar.scrollTop = scrollbar.scrollHeight;
    }
```

Во всех браузерах всё работает как надо. Когда вызываю эту функцию, скролл элемента content прокручивается вниз.И там остаётся.
В Safari же, эта функция срабатывает, скролл прокручивается но стоит провести мышкой над страницей, улетает вверх.Из за чего он так себя ведёт, как побороть?

Comment: вижу что проблема в css-grid.Работает нормально если ставлю высоту элемента в пикселях.В любом другом случае (fr,max-content) глючит скролл, улетая наверх.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Div content был css grid элементом. В нем были иконки которые появлялись по hover-у. Не знаю почему но в этот момент (в момент когда иконки становились display:block) Safari прокручивал скролл к верху страницы. Два решения, либо давать грид элементу четкую высоту в пикселях, либо отключить появление новых элементов после того как страница отрисовалась.